# SKAction.run not working until program execution paused/resumed

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, completionhandler

First time using SpriteKit - tapping a start button calls startLevel method in GameScene that has a player sprite fire two SKAction.run statements in a SKAction.sequence. The startLevel method has a completion block that triggers a message to the console and updates game state.

Tapping start displays the message, but the SKAction.run statements don't work unless I first pause program execution, and then click resume before tapping the start button. If I stop the level and tap a retry button, the same startLevel method is called, and it works fine without pausing execution.

Here's the method (player, marker, and door, are all optional objects that store their sprites; when tapping start, I verified that none of the sprites are nil, none of them are paused, and GameScene and SKView are not paused):

```
func startLevel(finished: () -> ()) {
    guard let player = player,
        let marker = marker,
        let door = door else {
        fatalError()
    }
    player.sprite.run(SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.run({ marker.pop(appear: true) }),
        SKAction.run({ door.slide(open: true) }),
    ]))
    finished()
}
```

Here's the GameScene code that calls startLevel:

```
startLevel(finished: { () -> () in
    print("ALERT: startLevel finished")
    levelStarted = true
})
```

I tried adding a run method completion block with a console message, and the message never prints. It seems that the player.sprite.run method is simply ignored (unless I pause execution first), and I don't understand why. Thanks for your help.

BTW - all the code above is outside GameScene’s update method, and the marker and door methods above are both used in didBegin() and didEnd(), and they work fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 11 Apple made Spritekit Scenes and objects paused by default.

What I do to combat this is...

in my SKScene

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //this ensures that the scene is not paused
    self.isPaused = false
}
```

and in each of my custom objects setup or init

```
self.isPaused = false
```

Comment: I do that too - note above I wrote none of the objects are paused; to be sure, I printed isPaused of each object before the SKAction; they were all false.

Comment: BTW - To be entirely clear, in addition to printing isPaused, I have also tried expressly setting isPaused to false for GameScene, SKView, and each object, immediately before the SKAction calls, and they still don't work until I first pause execution.

Comment: I know that you are going to disagree with me, but I would bet money that there is something that is paused that you are not accounting for. I had this same issue once and it took me and a colleague 3 days to figure it out. If I set a break point in my code and paused the game and the resumed it all my actions worked fine.

Comment: Where is startlevel called

Comment: Also, print the scene.isPaused in your update function

Comment: Ron, I'm not necessarily disagreeing; I've been hunting for days weeks now, and can't find it - how could something be paused, when I print isPaused immediately before the calls, and they're not paused?

Comment: KnightOfDragon, startLevel is called when the user taps the Start button; I load the game level and a side menu (containing the button) in didMove. The code is outside update, and I immediately return from update until levelStarted is set. However, for sake of argument, I checked in update, and scene and view are false (I set them to false in didMove).

Comment: @Steven, just because you made the calls before update, does not mean they are executed at that time.  SKActions fire after update is called, so it is possible to pause a node after your print statement without you being aware.  What do you mean "When program executed is paused/resume"  Do you mean like leaving the app and reentering it, or do you mean when you use your own pause/resume functions?  More details are going to be needed, and you need to provide an MCVE because you are doing something outside of the norm here, and in normal circumstances, RonMyschuk would be correct.

Comment: Before adding the menu with the Start button, the SKActions were part of a nested IF in update, and it happened there too; note above that I added isPaused prints in update immediately before the SKAction calls, and everything is false. What I mean by "when program execution is paused/resumed" is I wait until everything loads and the game is waiting for user input, then in Xcode, I click the Pause icon, let the game pause, then click the Play icon to resume the game, and tap the Start button - everything works as expected. What am I doing that's outside the norm? I am sincerely trying to learn

Comment: OK, so this is frustrating - I am new to Swift and SpriteKit, and don't know what MCVE is. Rather than look completely ignorant, I said nothing, and looked it up. I see lots of incidents where people are asking for them, but no one explains what they are. I'm sorry, but can someone throw me a bone please?

Comment: You need to help us help you. If it is difficult to get the information, people aren't going to invest the time. Post some more/relevant code! You say you've verified that the objects aren't paused, show us. show us the code and the results. show us your didMove func. show us your object inits. show us that you are making as much of an effort.

Comment: I understand, but I have to go to work, so I'll upload more code later; in the meantime, what is MCVE? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen! With your patient insistence, I figured it out; the answer was obvious, but it just didn't occur to me. I use SKReferenceNodes during object placement; I unpaused the sprites, but not the reference nodes. So, I unpaused the reference nodes during my loadLevel method, and everything works! It didn't occur to me until I started to create a MCVE for you, so thank you!

Comment: great! if this answer was helpful and correct please mark it as so. so others can learn from this